# Repository of Test Scripts

Tags: qa-developer, team-management

Are there any free tools available to store test scripts, execute and generate reports? For Ex : Test Link  ( I am already using but there are lots of issues )
I know that all the free tools has some bugs but some may not.
I would like to know any other tools which are available and user friendly.

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261626/simple-project-management-tool and the answers there should help.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Nope this is not similar to the question being asked there. Even I checked with answers Microsoft and all are paid versions. I need free tools which are available. Let me know in case you have any idea on this.

Comment: Read my answer to that question. "Visual Studio Online" (previously called "Team Foundation Service") has lots of facilities for managing tests cases, doing version control (ie storing test scripts and more) and it is free for up to 5 users.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I have read the answer, I have mentioned test link which I gave an example in my question which does not have any limitations of the users. I want to introduce a tool which is just like Testlink to my client as well as in my company which is really robust. So any idea on this ?

Answer (score 1):

What are your requirements ? what bothers you with TestLink ?

You can use a source control system (e.g. git) for storing the scripts and then execute them from Excel plus a VB script, a simple script in your favorite script language or a unit test framework (e.g. x-Unit, google test etc.) they are also capable of generating reports.

Comment: Bothers me with Testlink : I use testlink and then when I try to edit and save the script, it doesn't reflect and that is quite slow. Sometimes it doesn't open at all. We cannot download all the test scripts with suites. Requirements : My test cases has to be loaded and when I save them then it has to get updated and download them all in proper excel file if I want to keep a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Our team uses **TestLink** to manage hundreds of Test Cases (including automation scripts as attachments) in dozens of Test Suites, so I don't have a better *open source* recommendation from personal experience.

I have been on teams where we used [**HP Quality Center**](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/quality-center-quality-management/index.html?), and found it to be robust, but expen$ive.

There is, of course, yet another similar question on this site: ["*What test management system should I use?*"](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/what-test-management-system-should-i-use) that mentions a couple other commercial tools (TFS & QA Complete) and links to a crowd-sourced list of Test Tools (@www.ministryoftesting.com); the **Test Management** section of the list is currently about 40% of the way down the page.